# Website building workflow on iPad?

Tags: workflow, ipad

I'm going on a bike trip for a few months really soon. I'm dreaming about building a (photo) portfolio website. I've built one website on a desktop machine so far, so I'm not that experienced. I don't want to take a bulky and heavy laptop with me (kgs+needs electrical power), but my iPad Pro. I can edit my photos, write texts, etc. so far so good.

But are there any website-building workflows (apps, web apps) for iPads?

Some tips and hints would be great!!

Comment: Are you trying to code the website yourself or use a web building site like Wordpress, Wix, Squarespace, Etc?

Comment: Shopping requests like this are not really on topic for StackExchange websites

Comment: I only used wordpress before. i didnt liked it so far. so im not settled on something and totally open. just looking for an ipad based workflow.

Comment: There are a **ton** of "web building" apps in the app store.. what may or may not work for you *really* depends on what you do and don't know... no one here can answer that. The *reality* is you really only need a web browser and a good text editor to build a web site if you know markup.. otherwise.. just search the AppStore.

Comment: If its only for yourself, then why not use Google Drive or Dropbox ?

Comment: Neither GoogleDrive nor Dropbox are website building tools. That comment makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you do not know how to code HTML or CSS.

I would make a free account on Wix or Squarespace or similar and make my website there. They are browser-based, so as long as you have a browser on your Pad you have the tools.